# Jquery drop down menu for search box not showing up by clicking on icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

its an i tag (the image is) which uses css to display the icons through a cdn hosted stylesheet and how would I incorporate that.

So lets say there is a magnifying glass icon on the web page, we the user clicks on the icon , a div dropdown search box appears. that is what i am asking help for. not sure how to do it but I know I am close. The icon isnt clickable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#icon').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
});
  });


<section class="search">
<div id="icon"><i class="search-bar">CLICK</i></div>
<div class="search-dropdown hidden">   

    <input placeholder="search..." type="text"/>

</div>

</section>

.hidden
{
background-color: yellow;
display: none; 
}

#icon: 
{
border: 1px solid black;
height: 16px;
width: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rk12aa5g/2/ this is the code that won't work.

Comment: Works fine if you remember to include jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rk12aa5g/5/:

Answer (score 0):

check out this here it works

```
<style>
.hidden {
background-color: yellow;
display: none;
}
#icon: {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 16px;
width: 50px;
}
</style>
<section class="search">
<div id="icon"><i class="search-bar">CLICK</i>
</div>
<div class="search-dropdown hidden">
    <input placeholder="search..." type="text" />
</div>
</section>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#icon').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.search-dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
});
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/n3a52sa4/